# Passing parameters to ClaimsPrincipalPermission (Attribute)

Tags: c#, security, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to use claims to control access to a resource in MVC.  I'm struggling though when I try and protect resource with an argument.  For example, if I want to allow edit actions to be performed vehicles they own and have claims for:

I add claims:

- `http://tempuri/registration` : AA11XX
- `http://tempuri/registration` :  BB11YY

The I have an MVC Action such as:

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Operation = "Post", Resource = "Vehicle/{registration}")]
public ActionResult Edit(string registration)
{
//Stuff
}
```

I want to make sure that the parameter being passed into the `Edit` method is on the list of claims for registrations.  I know I can do this imperatively inside the action, but I want to do it declaratively.

I can use the WIF pipeline override the CheckAccess method.

```
       public class AuthorisationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
        {
            public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
{ ... }
```

AuthorizationContext includes the resource requested, and the claims the user has.  The missing link is knowing what parameter was passed into MVC action.

Is there a way of doing this, or am I approaching the whole thing the wrong way?

Thanks a lot,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way .NET attributes work, you can't pass in dynamic parameters - so this will not work.

We built a more flexible version that plays nicer with MVC and WebAPI and also has an imperative API - see this sample:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/SystemWeb/ClaimsAuthorizeSample

Comment: Thanks.  I did actually look at your example before.  In the end I took the routedata collection and compared them to the placeholder of the resource, so for example a resource of: "Get", "order/{orderid}" would look at the orderid from the routedata.  This proved to be a pain because of the differences in routing between mvc and web api.  I think on balance your solution is better, so I'm marking it as the answer.  I'm not quite sure why I was so set on it being it being declarative.  You're obviously an authority in these things, so if there's a reason my approach is bad, please let me know!